# Alternative of whenNew in mockito for this usecase

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, mockito

Can some help me to mock AnotherClass object.

Things I have tried so far.

1. MockConstruction
2. useConstructor with settings
3. When then statement

Powermockito we can not use for some reason.

```
ClassToBeTested {
  @Autowired
  DependencyOne dep1;
  @Autowired
  DependencyTwo dep2;

  method(){
    AnotherClass anotherClass = new AnotherClass(dep1,dep2);
anotherClass.someAction();
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think plain Mockito can mock constructors. You'll need PowerMock.

Comment: Are you able to make changes to ClassToBeTested ? If not then you can not to mock AnotherClass

Comment: I am not supposed to make changes to ClassToBeTested unfortunately

Comment: Explain to whoever told you that you can't modify `ClassToBeTested` that it has not been written in a testable manner, and that you need to change it.

Comment: Sure sir,will try to convey this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to handle this scenario by letting the call go to Another Class and then mocking the code present in some `action()` method with when then statements.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not supposed to change the source code of ClassToBeTested and can not use PowerMockito I would stick to a single possible approach, if acceptable:

```
public class ClassToBeTestedTest {
    @Mock
    DependencyOne dep1Mock;
    @Mock
    DependencyTwo dep2Mock;
    @Mock
    AnotherClass anotherClassMock;

    ClassToBeTested testInstance = new ClassToBeTestedTestSpecificImpl();

    private class ClassToBeTestedTestSpecificImpl extends ClassToBeTested {
        @Override
        method() {
            anotherClassMock.someAction();
        }
    }
    //test methods go here
}
```

Otherwise we can confidently state: ClassToBeTested is not testable in the given circumstances.

Comment: Hi @Alien, did manage to cover with tests your class? How?